# How can I use a std::variant with non-trivial user objects (constructed at a later time), and having the visitor use an auto lambda?

Tags: c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

I have code that is something like this:

```
using variant_t = std::variant<MyObj1, MyObj2, MyObj3>;

auto foo(){
    variant_t var;

    if (condition1){
        var = MyObj1{"A String"};
        // Other stuff
    } else if (condition2) {
        var = MyObj2{123, 12345};
        // Other stuff
    } else if (condition3) {
        var = MyObj3{SomeObject};
        // Other stuff
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error{};
    }

    return var;
}

int main(){
    auto var = foo();

    std::visit([&](auto& v){v.call_shared_function_name();}, var);
}
```

Assuming all of the MyObj's are non-trivial, is there a way to get this to work?

I know std::monostate will allow you to initialize the variant in this way and *actually* populate it later. But if I do so, I can't have the clean auto& lambda in the visitor and will have to create a visitor/lambda for each type.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might looks silly, or not that clean, but you actually need to initialize with one of those objects:

```
variant_t var = MyObj1{"A String"};
```

And it compiles fine, if you can't, please let me know and i'll remove the answer

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing that because the actual objects aren't as simply construct-able as passing in a string. But if there are no other options, I may just do that (fortunately this part of the code isn't called that often)

Comment: @user9760017 idk.. maybe adding a "Error" object in the list of the variant that has the call_shared_function_name that throws every time is called, and initialize the variant with that object?...

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea. Perhaps I will do that if no other standard alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: @user9760017 happy to have been helpful